# Refer to $this from anonymous function inside a class method

Tags: php

I have some code that's run within a method (it's a CakePHP view):

This works:

```
$this->foo();
```

This doesn't:

```
function bar() {
    $this->foo();
} // Using $this when not in object context
```

Neither does this:

```
function bar() {
    global $this;
    $this->foo();
} // Cannot re-assign $this
```

Nor this:

```
$that = $this;
$bar = function() {
    global $that;
    $that->foo();
} // Trying to get property of non-object
```

I'd like to use the object's library function from within this method, but `bar` has to stay a local subprocedure (moving it to be a class method would be pointless). Any solutions or workarounds?

Comment: can you pass $this to the function? bar($this);

Comment: As of 5.4, you'll [be able to reference `$this` directly](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) inside the anonymous function.  5.4 is not yet suitable for production use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP 5.3:

```
$that = $this;
$bar = function() use (&$that) { /* the reference isn't really required
                                    since it's an object handle */
    $that->foo();
};
```

With PHP 5.4, the above hack isn't required.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is pass $this as a parameter to bar()...

```
function bar($that)
{
    $that->foo();
}

// and to call from within class method:
$this->foo($this);
```